# angular2, what is read: property used for in ViewChild?

Tags: angular

I understand and use often the @ViewChild, but what's the {read} prop used for?

as in: @ViewChild('putStuffHere', {read: ViewContainerRef}) putStuffHere;

see code below:

```
import {Component, ViewChild, ViewContainerRef, ComponentResolver} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  template `<h1>my-component</h1>`
})
class MyComponent{}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <h2>Above</h2>
    <div #putStuffHere></div>
    <h2>Below</h2>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  @ViewChild('putStuffHere', {read: ViewContainerRef}) putStuffHere;

  constructor(
      public view:ViewContainerRef,
      public compResolver:ComponentResolver
  ){}

  ngAfterViewInit(){
    this.compResolver.resolveComponent(MyComponent)
      .then(factory => {
        this.putStuffHere.createComponent(factory);    
      })

  }
}
```

regards

Sean

Answer (score 3):

It allows having access to a `ViewContainerRef` instance instead of an `ElementRef` one.

Here is a sample:

```
@ViewChild('putStuffHere') putStuffHere1:ElementRef;
@ViewChild('putStuffHere', {read: ViewContainerRef}) putStuffHere2:ElementRef;
```